# Word 2007 files launching new window instead of displaying inline

Tags: iframe, asp-classic, ms-office, mime-types

I have a web app which allows the user to upload files and then view them in the browser. This is done by displaying them in-line with an IFrame. This works fine for all file types (e.g. .doc, .xls, .pdf) except Office 2007 formats .docx and .xlsx, which are launching the application in a new window.

I'm using these values for the 'Content-Type' header:

```
docx - "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document"
xlsx - "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"
```

The 'Content-Disposition' header is "inline; filename=example.docx".

This is a classic ASP script which returns the raw file in the response, requested via the 'src' attribute of the IFrame and served by IIS 6. I DON'T have Office 2007 installed on my PC, but I do have the Office 2007 Compatibility Pack. However this has also been tested on a client that does have Office 2007 and the issue remains.

How can I force these file types to open inline in the browser rather than opening a new window?

Any help appreciated.

EDIT:

I should have mentioned this only needs to work in IE8.

Answer (score 0):

@Lee D: Even though you're explicitly setting the Content-Type (and have the Office 2007 Compatibility Pack installed on your PC), I think you should add those MIME types to your web server (it's in IIS Manager under *Server Properties* and then *MIME Types*) to see if that's the missing ingredient.

Comment: Hasn't helped I'm afraid. Thanks for the suggestion.